# vba code to cycle through listbox values, copy to cell and print?

Tags: excel, vba

I need a code that will copy the first value in my ListBox2 to cell C8 in sheet called "Gym Weekly Template" (which is Sheet1), print the sheet and then loop to the next value and repeat the same process, repeating until all the values in the ListBox2 has been copied and printed, in which I want the sheet to reset to how it appeared prior to the code running.

Is anyone able to help with that?

Thank you!

Jackson

I currently have written the following code for selecting the first value

```
Dim i As Long
    For i = ListBox1.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
        ListBox2.ListIndex = I
    Next i
```

Comment: does the order matter? It will be easiest to just go from 1 to the end

Comment: Not at all, I'm just not sure of the code to write it. I need a print out for each individual value though as vlookup code will interact with each value differently

Answer (score 0):

The following code will loop through each item within your listbox.  For each item, the value is entered in C8 and the worksheet is printed...

```
Dim vOrigVal As Variant
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Long

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Gym Weekly Template")

vOrigVal = ws.Range("C8").Value

With Me.ListBox1
    For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
        ws.Range("C8").Value = .List(i)
        ws.PrintOut
    Next i
End With

ws.Range("C8").Value = vOrigVal
```